# Is there a way to view metadata functions?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an NullReferenceException ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") thrown when I try to set a cursor, but none of the objects are null. At this point MainForm.Form.Cursor is WaitCursor, and theCursor is set to Default. I even have this check to make sure:

```
If MainForm.Form.Cursor IsNot Nothing AndAlso theCursor IsNot Nothing Then
    MainForm.Form.Cursor = theCursor 'exception thrown here
End If
```

I'm guessing that inside the setter something is null, but is hard to know without being able to see the code. Is there a read-only version somewhere of the metadata code for this? Or any ideas of what could it be?

Comment: Note that the code is only checking if `.Cursor` is nothing, the `MainForm` and `.Form` could also be null.

Comment: yeah that is true, but when I check it on the debugger it actually comes that MainForm.Form.Cursor is waitcursor. MainForm is a class and Form is set to the project (not Null).

Comment: Instead of setting theCursor, what happens if you set it to some default one, like the hourglass?

Comment: You mean like "MainForm.Form.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor"? I still get an exception.

Comment: One of those has to be null.  Test them.  `If MainForm IsNot Nothing AndAlso MainForm.Form IsNot Nothing AndAslo MainForm.Form.Cursor IsNot Nothing AndAlso ...`

Comment: Ok guys so here is what was going on. There was an event being handled right before it, and at the very end of it there was a null reference. The previous code was in a Finally clause which I failed to mention because I didn't know this code is executed even after an exception. Thanks for you help!